# How to make y/n user input loop if the user input is not y or n?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have to make a text based game in java programming. I want to implement loop that loops if the String user input is not y or n and if they are y or n then follow along the code.

I added a do while loop twice. First time the loop kept looping infinitely.
And then the second time loop kept looping even thought the input was y or n.

```
char YNinput = ' ';
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Do you want to play (Yes or No) ");
YNinput = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
```

There is no error right now since i used if else statements, but when i add loops there are a lot of errors.
Ecpected - Loop that loops only if the input isn't y or n, and after looping again if the input is y or n, then do accound to the code.

Comment: Post your code with loops. Tell us what the errors are. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop was probably the result of having an incorrect condition on your loop. Try this:

```
char YNinput = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.print("Do you want to play (Yes or No) ");
    YNinput = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
} while (YNinput != 'y' && YNinput != 'n');

sc.close();
```